# Change url after I updated DB

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

After I have updated the title of a post in my DB I want to redirect to a page where the second uri would be the new title instead of the old...how can I do that in express js ?

```
app.post('/blog_update/:title', function(req, res){
  var oldTitle = req.params.title
  var newTitle = req.body.post.title
  if(req.body.post.submit){
    posts.update({title : oldTitle}, {
                  title : req.body.post.title,
          body : req.body.post.body,
                  tags : req.body.post.tags
    }, function(err){
      if(err) throw err;

      else{
    posts.findOne({title : req.body.post.title}, function(err, arr){
      if(err) throw err

      res.render('blog_update' , {locals:{title:'Updated Successfully!', post: arr }});
    })
      }
    })
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
res.redirect("/blog_update/" + newTitle);
```

Construct a new uri based on the `newTitle` then call `res.redirect`

```
app.post('/blog_update/:title', function(req, res) {
    var oldTitle = req.params.title
    var newTitle = req.body.post.title
    if (req.body.post.submit) {
        posts.update({
            title: oldTitle
        }, {
            title: req.body.post.title,
            body: req.body.post.body,
            tags: req.body.post.tags
        }, function(err) {
            if (err) throw err;

            else {
                posts.findOne({
                    title: req.body.post.title
                }, function(err, arr) {
                    if (err) throw err

                    res.redirect("/blog_update/" + newTitle);
                })
            }
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks it just gives me a url saying : undefined. Redirecting to http://localhost:8080/blog_update/new_title , and then I have to click...do I also have to render a page in order to do this automatically?

Comment: @rabidmachine9 did you ever solve this to make it go automatically?